# How to get the values from different node in XML using XSLT mapping with condition

Tags: xslt, groovy, xslt-2.0

I've got an xml similar to this:

[Input XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiYXi.png)

I need to get the Manager details (company , cost_center) if the Person ../company = 001

So, basically it should be the output like that:

[Required XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuZn4.png)

I knew this can be done with XSLT and Groovy scripts but i am not able to write the code.

So Can you please help?

Comment: Why are you not able to write the code?

Comment: Don't link to images, post your actual code and input/output in your question.

Comment: Use a **key** to resolve cross-references: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key